# Entity Framework 7 relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm not quite sure what I'm missing here. It seems like a no brainer but for some reason, Category is always coming back as null and I always run into these issues when using Entity Framework. I'd like to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Product ID, Product Name and Category ID has data but Category is always null. I'm trying to pull back a list of products as well as the category that the product is associated with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Using the infamous Northwind database

```
[Table("Products")]
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public virtual Categories Category { get; set; }
}

[Table("Categories")]
public class Categories
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Products> Product { get; set; }
}
```

DbContext (relevant code)

```
public DbSet<Categories> Categories { get; set; } 
public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
```

This is the code that's returning the products from my repository

```
 public IEnumerable<Products> GetAll()
 {
     return _db.Products.AsEnumerable();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide the query your using that is pulling back a null category?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete added.

Comment: return _db.Products.Include("Categories").AsEnumerable();

Comment: @janina Products does not contain a definition of Include

Comment: import using System.Data.Entity on top

Comment: @janina that's a namespace for ef6. I'm using VS2015 and ASP.NET 5 (or whatever the new name of it is now) :)

Comment: using namespace Microsoft.Data.Entity from EntityFramework.Core and change query Products.Include(x => x.Category)

Comment: @syned that works...but now I'm confused as to why I need to call Include()

Comment: Just _db.Products.Select(s => s) can work?

Comment: @Anonymous Because by default EF7 does not have lazy loading yet, so you need to specify loading of related entities with .Include() method. Maybe in the future it will be supported

Comment: @syned thanks! When you get a minute could you write an answer up so I can accept? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use extension method Include() from Microsoft.Data.Entity namespace from EntityFramework.Core assembly.

```
    using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
    ...
    return _db.Products.Include(p => p.Category).AsEnumerable();
```

Because EF7 doesn't support lazy loading for related entities yet like it was implemented in EF6. So you need to load all related entities with .Include method. Maybe in the future, it will be supported.

You can follow the roadmap of EF7 here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap